# Extracting string text before whitespace

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of character data which I want to convert to numeric, it looks like this:

```
[231] "34.05" "35.05" "36.05" "37.05" "1.09 " "2.09 " "3.09 " "4.09 " "5.09 " "6.09 "
[241] "7.09 " "8.09 " "9.09 " "46.86" "1.9 y" "2.9 y" "3.9 y" "4.9 y" "5.9 y" "6.9 y"
```

Some entries are perfectly fine, such as "`37.05`", but some we're wrongly extracted, like `"4.9 y`". I want to extract only the parts of each entry.

What I have is:

```
data = stringr::str_extract(data, "([^/]+)(?=:space:)")
```

But I get a bunch of NAs. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the float values at the start of the string, so use

```
x <- c("33.72", "34.72", "35.72", "36.72", "37.72", "29.05", "30.05", "31.05", "32.05", "33.05",
       "34.05", "35.05", "36.05", "37.05", "1.09 ", "2.09 ", "3.09 ", "4.09 ", "5.09 ", "6.09 ",
       "7.09 ", "8.09 ", "9.09 ", "46.86", "1.9 y", "2.9 y", "3.9 y", "4.9 y", "5.9 y", "6.9 y")
as.double(sub("^(\\d+\\.\\d+).*", "\\1", x))
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/tKKzB7) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WMECmM/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(\\d+\\.\\d+)` - Capturing group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): 1 or more digits, a dot and then 1+ digits
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars as many as possible.

**NOTE**: If there can be floats and integers use `as.double(sub("^(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", x))`.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B).*):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove everthing that is not a digit or a period.

```
as.double(gsub("[^0-9\\.]+", "", x))
# [1] 33.72 34.72 35.72 36.72 37.72 29.05 30.05 31.05 32.05 33.05 34.05 35.05 36.05 37.05
#[15]  1.09  2.09  3.09  4.09  5.09  6.09  7.09  8.09  9.09 46.86  1.90  2.90  3.90  4.90
#[29]  5.90  6.90
```

**data**

```
x <- c("33.72", "34.72", "35.72", "36.72", "37.72", "29.05", "30.05", "31.05", "32.05", "33.05",
       "34.05", "35.05", "36.05", "37.05", "1.09 ", "2.09 ", "3.09 ", "4.09 ", "5.09 ", "6.09 ",
       "7.09 ", "8.09 ", "9.09 ", "46.86", "1.9 y", "2.9 y", "3.9 y", "4.9 y", "5.9 y", "6.9 y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Even easier with `parse_number` from readr package

```
> library(readr)
> parse_number(x)
 [1] 33.72 34.72 35.72 36.72 37.72 29.05 30.05 31.05 32.05 33.05 34.05 35.05 36.05 37.05  1.09  2.09  3.09  4.09  5.09
[20]  6.09  7.09  8.09  9.09 46.86  1.90  2.90  3.90  4.90  5.90  6.90
```

you can even change your actual pattern from `"([^/]+)(?=:space:)"` to `"\\d+\\.\\d*"`:

```
stringr::str_extract(x, "\\d+\\.\\d*")
```